# Need jquery blinking text to only blink for a period of 8 seconds, then stop

Tags: jquery

I need to stop flashing text after 8 seconds. Everything is working perfectly except being able to stop it after the 8 seconds. I am new to this, need help...

Here is code that I am using, please give suggestions or add to this code what I need for it to stop after 8 seconds :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="msg"> <strong><font color="red">text example</font></strong></p> </div>

<script type="text/javascript" >
function blink(selector){
    $(selector).fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $(this).fadeIn('slow', function(){
            blink(this);
        });
    });
}

blink('#msg');
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can try such an addition to your code:

```
var stopBlinking = false;
setTimeout(function() 
{
    stopBlinking = true;
}, 8000);

function blink(selector) {
    $(selector).fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).fadeIn('slow', function() {
            if (!stopBlinking)
            {
                blink(this);
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Look at the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/K5FHY/2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="msg"> <strong><font color="red">text example</font></strong></p> </div>

<script type="text/javascript" >
var timer = 0;

var timeSpan = setInterval(function(){
    timer++;
},1000);

function blink(selector)
{
    if(timer == 0)
        timeSpan;
    $(selector).fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $(this).fadeIn('slow', function(){
            if(timer < 8)
               blink(this);
                    else
                    {
                  clearInterval(timeSpan);
              $(this).hide();
                    }
        });
    });
}

blink('#msg');
</script>
```

try this out

Comment: Hi Uttara, tried this but it doesn't seem to work. Text stayed on for 8 seconds, then faded out, then in again. Am I missing something? I need the text to flash like it is standard but need the text to stop flashing altogether after 8 seconds (ie. it must stop flashing completely). I am not referring to the interval bewteen the text flashes and fade out/fade in but to stop the text flashing after 8 seconds completely. Thanks for your help, appreciate it

Comment: thanks a mil, works perfectly. Only thing now is, need the text to dissapear after the 8 seconds...is this difficult?

Comment: try out have added to hide the text after 8 seconds

Comment: Sorry to come back to you. Lost the code without the "hide" text. I am not sure which is better - for the text to stay on after the 8 seconds or to disappear. If I want it to stay on afterwards...

Comment: just remove $(this).hide(); from else part

Comment: Thanks U! You have helped a great deal!

Answer (score 0):

```
function blink(selector){

  // all blink happen with 8 seconds interval

  setTimeout(function() {

   $(selector).fadeOut('slow', function(){

        $(this).fadeIn('slow', function(){

            blink(this); // recursive function will call after fadeIn finish

        });
   });

  }, 8000); // set interval to 8 seconds
}
```