# stop blinking text javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a short script, where a text is blinking. But I cannot really figure out how I can stop the blinking after fx 3 blinks. Does anybody know how I can add that to my script?

Best Regards Julie

HTML

```
<div class="blink">blinking text</div>
    non-blinking
<div class="blink">more blinking text</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.flash{
    background: yellow;
}

.noflash{
    background: white;
}
```

JS:

```
function blink(selector){
    $(selector).fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $(this).fadeIn('slow', function(){
            blink(this);
        });
    });
}

blink('.blink');
```

Comment: this question is already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812473/need-jquery-blinking-text-to-only-blink-for-a-period-of-8-seconds-then-stop

Comment: Hello Filip. I have looked at those questions before, but there is not anything how the blinking is stopping again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 function blink(selector, repeat){
    if(!repeat) return;
    $(selector).fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $(this).fadeIn('slow', function(){
            blink(this, repeat - 1);
        });
    });
 }

 blink('.blink', 3);
```

So you can control how many times it will blink.

Comment: There actually wasn't too many braces @jcubic, just tested it.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice that the if don't have opening brace.

Answer (score 2):

You can build chain of effects without recursion:

```
function blink(selector){
    var chain = $(selector);
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        chain = chain.fadeOut('slow').fadeIn('slow');
    }
}

blink('.blink');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this (untested):

```
function blink(selector, count){
  count = count || 1;
  if (count <= 3) {
    $(selector).fadeOut('slow', function(){
      $(this).fadeIn('slow', function(){
        blink(this, ++count);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. I will try this when I come home from work